# Write to Cisco Switch with c# System.IO.Ports.SerialPort doesn't always work

Tags: c#, serial-port, putty, cisco

i wrote a simple code in `c#` `using System.IO.Ports.SerialPort` that opens a serialport connection to a Cisco switch and writes to it.

it works fine but only if i open the connection via `putty.exe` first and then close putty, and run my code.

then my code works fine for a day WITHOUT PUTTY(writes successfully to the switch)  but tomorrow when i try my code again it doesn't work unless i open putty again and connect to the switch the same way.

any ideas why this happens? 
the switch is Cisco Switch 2960cx.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

1) Add timeouts (example)

```
  _serialPort.ReadTimeout = 500;
  _serialPort.WriteTimeout = 500;
```

2) Immediately after opening the connection

```
  _serialPort.Write(new byte[] { 13, 10 }, 0, 2);
```